# Explicit extensions for Heisenberg groups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, galois-groups

Let $G$ be the $p$-adic Heisenberg group $\begin{pmatrix} 1&\mathbb Z_p&\mathbb Z_p\\&1&\mathbb Z_p\\&&1\end{pmatrix}$. Is it possible to write an explicit extension $K/k$, where $k$ is a number field, such that $\mathrm{Gal}(K/k)\cong G$?